# How to pan/zoom an image and an overlay simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using [jquery.panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom) to pan and zoom an image in response to mouse or touch events.  This works fine, but now I'd like to zoom the image together with an overlay (either a SVG file or another image).  The overlay and the image are exactly the same size, I just want them to behave as a single image with respect to pan and zoom.

I tried putting them both in a div, like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <img src="image.jpg" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 500; height: 500;">
  <img src="overlay.svg" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 500; height: 500;">
</div>

<script>
  $("#mydiv").panzoom();
</script>
```

The layout gets messed up when I do that.

How can I pan/zoom an image and overlay (or several images) simultaneously?

(I'd like to keep using jquery.panzoom since that seems to work very well on my target platforms, but if there is another library that does the same that could also work)

Answer (score 1):

According to their [documentation](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/blob/master/README.md#loading-panzoom), this should work:

```js
(function() {
  var $section = $('#collectionId');
  $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
    $set: $section.find('.parent > div')
  });
})();
```

```html
<section id="collectionId">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="panzoom">
      <img src="image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="overlay.svg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="anotherOverlay.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```